# I use the Firefox browser console to dubug my javascript code, but it is constantly being FLOODED with entries for background.js - can I stop this?

Tags: browser, console

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://tlx.3lift.com/header/auction?lib=prebid&v=8.26.0&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_split.asp&tmax=1250&gdpr=false&us_privacy=1---. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

and thousands more, all the time.

Haven't tried anything except searching the Internet. All I get is a lot about Chrome extension, none of which hints at a solution for me. I tried managing extensions in Firefox - could not find  anything about Chrome.